# Play video using NSData with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, avplayer, rncryptor

I have encrypted the video file(.mov) using RNCryptor Library after downloading the file. Now I want to play this video file using AVPlayer. When I decrypt the file it returns NSData. How I can play that video using NSData in AVPlayer.

for encryption I have added following code:-

```
        let fm = FileManager.default
        guard let docUrl = fm.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
            print("Unable to reach the documents folder")
            return
        }

        let localUrl = docUrl.appendingPathComponent(String.init(format: "%@", downloadModel.fileName))


        let data = try Data.init(contentsOf: localUrl)
        let password = "secret"
        let cipherText = RNCryptor.encrypt(data: data, withPassword: password)
```

for decryption of video file

```
        let cipherText = UserDefaults.sharedInstance.getCipherText()
        // Decryption
        do {
            let originalData = try RNCryptor.decrypt(data: cipherText, withPassword: "secret")
            debugPrint(originalData)
            let dataString = String.init(data: originalData, encoding: .utf16)
            let url = URL.init(string: dataString!)
            configureVideoPlayer(url: url!)

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

but url is nil. How I can achieve this.

Comment: Can you show us the result for dataString

Comment: Try UTF8 encoding

Comment: utf8 encoding is giving me nil string